# Puzzle of the day - three in one Sudoku?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

A three in one sudoku. Have fun

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Where did you find this?

Comment: @DanielMathias I'm pretty sure its self-made

Comment: Ok, I've started trying to solve this, but sleep has won. This is *HARD*! :P

Comment: I've made some progress, filled in 14 squares, but yeah, hard.

Comment: This one definitely should have had a 'no computers' tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full grid:

> [image]

Honestly, I just worked with three [Sudoku Solver](https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm) tabs. But at least I watched how this puzzle could be solved with logical deduction ;)